# Semantic warning on xcode 4

Tags: macos, cocoa, forward-declaration

I'm getting a semantic warning on Xcode 4 :
***Declaration of 'struct sockaddr_in' will not be visible outside of this function***
the struct seems to be declared in netinet/in.h

The warning is getting marked on Reachability.h, its a class that I downloaded from Apple examples.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

typedef enum {
    NotReachable = 0,
    ReachableViaWiFi,
    ReachableViaWWAN
} NetworkStatus;
#define kReachabilityChangedNotification @"kNetworkReachabilityChangedNotification"

@interface Reachability: NSObject
{
    BOOL localWiFiRef;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef;
}

//reachabilityWithHostName- Use to check the reachability of a particular host name. 
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithHostName: (NSString*) hostName;

//reachabilityWithAddress- Use to check the reachability of a particular IP address. 
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr_in*) hostAddress;

//reachabilityForInternetConnection- checks whether the default route is available.  
//  Should be used by applications that do not connect to a particular host
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForInternetConnection;

//reachabilityForLocalWiFi- checks whether a local wifi connection is available.
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForLocalWiFi;

//Start listening for reachability notifications on the current run loop
- (BOOL) startNotifier;
- (void) stopNotifier;

- (NetworkStatus) currentReachabilityStatus;
//WWAN may be available, but not active until a connection has been established.
//WiFi may require a connection for VPN on Demand.
- (BOOL) connectionRequired;
@end
```

I don't understand the warning, can someone explain it to me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Someone filed a bug report against the behavior and got a response from someone [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9203). Essentially, the problem is that you're declaring a new struct (so far as the compiler can tell) in the parameter of the method, so it will not be accessible elsewhere.

There is a quick fix for it. Simply add the following line to `Reachability.h`:

```
#import <netinet/in.h>
```

Comment: See @brainjam's answer for a more elegant solution that doesn't introduce header file bloat.

Answer (score 20):

You're declaring a new struct in a method parameter, as opposed to at file scope.

The warning will go away if you add a forward declaration at the beginning of the file (somewhere before the `@interface` section).

```
struct sockaddr_in ;
```

Doing this instead of `#import <netinet/in.h>` avoids header file bloat.

(Speaking of reducing header bloat you can cut down header use in `Reachability.h` by replacing the lines

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

with

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Add #import  in Reachability.h to get away with this