# Xcode 4.2 - declaration of '...' will not be visible outside of this function warning

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ios5

I use Apple Reachability class from Apple Sample code
[Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)

in Xcode 4.2 and new Apple 3.0 compiler I get warning in this class that

```
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr_in*) hostAddress;
```

*declaration of 'struct sockaddr_in*' will not be visible outside of this function*

I am not good at classic C %) so I dont understand how I can fix this warning or may be I can ignore it at all.

Thx

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8684721/449161

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Add `#import <netinet/in.h>` in Reachability.h to get away with this

Comment: I forgot to format it as code and stackoverflow removed <netinet/in.h> for me :(

Comment: And take care: the import already exists in Reachability.m - but it's also needed in Reachability.h

Comment: `#include`, not `#import`. Due to subtle differences between C and Objective-C headers, you should only use `#import` for Objective-C. Pure C should continue to use `#include`.

Comment: what's the difference between #include and #import?

Comment: Anyway I got rid of #import <netinet/in.h>
#import <netinet6/in6.h> out of the .m file and add that to .h file

Comment: @Jonathan-Grynspan what differences? Is there any reason not to use `import` with C headers inside ObjC module?

Comment: `#import` will prevent a header from being brought into a compilation unit twice. `#include` will allow it (and then guard macros are used to prevent duplicate symbols.) There are some headers that *expect* to be brought in twice.

Comment: Instead of the #import, you can also do a forward declaration of the missing struct. Add a single "struct sockaddr_in;" line to the .h file

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan - I have to disagree; `#import` is always the preferable option.  It removes the need to have a bunch of `#ifndef SOMEFILE_H` nonsense in every single header file.  If someone set up their header so that it *needs* to be brought in twice (or more) then they have done something wrong.  In any other case the only argument in favor of using `#include` is a pedantic one about maintaining portability to compilers that do not support `#import`.  Which is silly, in my opinion.

Comment: @aroth: Your opinion, while entitled to you, is wrong, for the reasons previously stated.

Comment: @aroth - "If someone set up their header so that it needs to be brought in twice (or more) then they have done something wrong." - not really, you can make templates using macros, e.g. for hashtables, etc. which you *need* to include multiple times with different defs above so that different structures are defined. Example: https://klib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/klib/trunk/klib/khash.h

Comment: This was one interesting discussion I have read on stackoverflow. Thanks @JonathanGrynspan